# Webpack builds successfully, but hangs without exiting

Tags: webpack

Here is my `webpack.config.js`, I don't see anything weird in it (i.e. infinite thread pool) that would create a hangup, yet I always have to manually Ctrl+C the step to continue. This was a minor nuisance, but I want to resolve it while refactoring some deploy code.

```
const path = require('path');
const version = require('./VERSION').version;
const SentryWebpackPlugin = require('@sentry/webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  entry: './client/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'client.js',
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: 'ui',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-flow'],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new SentryWebpackPlugin({
      include: '.',
      ignoreFile: '.sentrycliignore',
      ignore: [
          'node_modules',
          'lib',
          'server',
          'flow-typed',
          'scripts',
          'webpack.config.js'
      ],
      configFile: 'sentry.properties',
      release: version
    })
  ],
  watch: true,
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: ['test', 'node_modules', 'scripts'],
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
  },
};
```

Here is what my `package.json` looks like:

```
{
    "name": "investomation-api",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "...",
    "private": true,
    "main": "server.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "NODE_ENV=production npm install && webpack --mode production",
        "start": "PORT=443 NODE_ENV=production pm2 start server/start.js",
        "restart": "pm2 restart 0",
        "start:dev": "PORT=3002 NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/dev-start.js",
        "flow": "flow",
        "server:upload": "cd scripts && ./upload"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "..."
    },
    "nodemonConfig": {
        "ignore": [
            "cypress/",
            "node_modules/",
            "scripts/",
            "tests/"
        ]
    },
    "prettier": {
        "tabWidth": 4
    },
    "author": "Alexander Tsepkov",
    "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE",
    "dependencies": {
        "@mapbox/geojson-types": "^1.0.2",
        "bcrypt": "^3.0.7",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
        "connect-sqlite3": "^0.9.11",
        "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "csv-parser": "^2.3.2",
        "d3": "^5.15.0",
        "dialog-polyfill": "^0.5.0",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "ejs": "^2.7.4",
        "express-session": "^1.17.0",
        "https": "^1.0.0",
        "knex": "^0.21.1",
        "morgan": "^1.9.1",
        "multer": "^1.4.2",
        "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
        "nodemailer": "^6.4.2",
        "objection": "^2.1.3",
        "passport": "^0.4.1",
        "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
        "sharp": "^0.25.4",
        "sqlite3": "^4.1.1",
        "stripe": "^7.15.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/node": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/register": "^7.8.3",
        "@sentry/webpack-plugin": "^1.9.3",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
        "css.escape": "^1.5.1",
        "cypress": "^4.5.0",
        "flow-bin": "^0.107.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "jsdom": "^15.2.1",
        "mocha": "^6.2.2",
        "nodemon": "^1.19.4",
        "test-drone": "0.0.13",
        "webpack": "^4.41.5",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.1"
    }
}
```

I spawn the process via `npm run build`, the `client.js` is correctly built, but the webpack build process never terminates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out my problem. I use the same webpack config in dev and production. In dev, it's configured to watch for file changes and restart the server. I didn't realize that this also meant that it was watching for file changes in production ready to rebuild the bundle. Changing the line `watch: true` to `watch: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && true` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Hi I have been struggling with this, but I figured it out :)

Webpack5 will stay on watch mode and we need a way to determine when it is finished or not. You can use my solution here on your webpack.config file, input into the plugins array. Will exit the watch mode and will proceed to next step :) hope this works for you

```
    // Exit the process when built successfully
{
  apply: (compiler) => {
    compiler.hooks.done.tap("DonePlugin", (stats) => {
      console.log("Compile is done !");
      setTimeout(() => {
        process.exit(0);
      });
    });
  },
},
```

Comment: You are my lord and savior.

Answer (score 3):

This can be because of the *webpack-bundle-analyzer* plugin. Disable or remove it for production builds.